# Change role's settings influence post-thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, user-roles

In my theme functions.php i get code:

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
if(!current_user_can('delete_others_posts')) {
remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=slide');
}
}
```

but then in role Author user can't edit images for thumbnail - he gives info:

```
    Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1286
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll guess that `admin_init` is too early for [`remove_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page), the hook should be `admin_menu`.